How to avoid blurring when using TBitmap.Rotate?
I'm trying to rotate a bitmap in Firemonkey.
The below works as intended:
procedure Rotate(Source, Dest: TBitmap; Angle: Single);
begin
  if Assigned(Source) then
  begin
    Dest.Assign(Source);
    Dest.Rotate(Angle);
  end;
end;

Even just reducing the method to the following does the same:
procedure Rotate(Source, Dest: TBitmap; Angle: Single);
begin
  Source.Rotate(Angle);
end;

However, when providing arbitrary angles, after a few calls to Rotate there is a slight blur effect gradually been applied. You can see this from the included image below where I apply the rotation at a 5° angle (5 seperate times).

You can see it loses it's sharpness over time and I am unsure what is causing it or how to prevent it?

When you rotate pixels at angles which are not even multiples of 45°, pixels have to be distorted/generated to produce the result. That doesn't happen at 45° rotations, where pixels can be translated precisely. To minimize the effect, keep a copy of the original bitmap and copy+rotate it as needed. Do not rotate a bitmap that has already been rotated. The loss of sharpness is cumulative.

I agree with Remy Lebeau. Always do rotation from the original source image and not from the image that has already been rotated. And if you need this only for visual representation then simply change the RotationAngle of the component you are showing your picture in.

Try in delphi Athens with Skia enabled, it's a much more powerfull graphic engine

@RemyLebeau That doesn't happen at 45° rotations, where pixels can be translated precisely. It should certainly be 90 degrees.

@BrakNicku yes, you're right, I meant 90°
